# Unclear python syntax

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm having a hard time understanding the following list comprehension:

```
words = [word for line in open('words.txt', 'r') for word in line.split()]
```

I understand the first part, the `word for line in open('words.txt', 'r')` but the second part confuses me. Does it mean *for each line in `words.txt`, loop for each `word` on the split `line`*?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what it means.

Comment: @JeanFrançoisFabre: that dupe is for using a list comprehension as the expression of another list comprehension, not for using multiple for loops in a single list comprehension.

Comment: The second answer there may cover this case, but the answer is in entirely the wrong context there (it is the wrong answer for the question posted).

Comment: I note that the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) covers the syntax in enough detail, including multiple `for` loops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so anyone can post any list comprehension and gets a personalized explanation?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: no, we just had to find a better dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loops are nested, from left to right. You can write it out as regular loops like this:

```
words = []
for line in open('words.txt', 'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        words.append(word)
```

So the expression before the `for` loops is the final value added to the produced list, and all the `for` loops (and any `if` tests) are executed nested inside the preceding loop or test.

So, yes, for each line in the opened file, the line is split and the resulting words from those lines are added to the list being built.